# Custom rendering of nested field in django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a table defined like this, where I want to apply custom rendering for a field:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class SetTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = (
             "series.title",
        )

    def render_series_title(self, value):
        return 'x'
```

For simple fields on the object itself (i.e. without a period) this works. But when there is a nested relationship (in this case, the `Set` model has a foreign key relationship to `Series`, and I want to display the `Title` field from the series), the custom rendering is not triggered. I have tried `render_title`, `render_series_title`, `render_series__title`, etc., and none of these gets called.

The table is specified as the `table_class` in a `django_filters` view, and is displaying the data fine, except that it is using the default rendering and bypassing the custom rendering function.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accessor` for that:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class SetTable(tables.Table):
     series_title = tables.Column(accessor='series.title')  # or newer version series__title
     class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = (
             "series_title",
        )
```

Unfortunately, I did not find where to see the documentation for it (there is some indication of accessor [here](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#using-accessors)), but I checked the source code about [`Column`](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/columns/base.py#L161) and [`Accessor`](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/utils.py#L287) classes.